# SwiftUI changing environment object re-created observed object in same view

Tags: swiftui, environment, combine, observedobject, environmentobject

So, I have few steps, last one contains **EnvironmentObject** and **ObservedObject**. The issue is, when I try to modify **EnvironmentObject** **(lane 68)**  it re-creates **ObservedObject**.
Can any one explain me why this happens? Any solution to keep my **ObservedObject** with original state?

As far as I know it possible to change ObservedObject to StateObject, but I am using iOS 13+ so... I need other solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 47 - body is reevaluated so new instance of `ObservedStuff` is created, so make it as property and pass it in, like

```
struct TestView_A: View {
   ...
   private let model = ObservedStuff()

   var body: some View {
      NavigationLink(destination: TestView_B(viewModel: self.model) ...
   }
}
```

Comment: question, but it's still gonna be evaluated if I remove if from lane 47 and put it on lane 54?

Comment: Yes, sure, because `TestView_B` is recreated in that place.